# Python - How to remove duplicate sequence of letters from string (cannot split by spacing)

Tags: python, pandas

This is different than removing repeating characters or repeating words, as explained below.

- 'Blue Valley StarsBlue Valley' should equal 'Blue Valley Stars'
- 'West Michigan WhitecapsWest Michigan' should equal 'West Michigan Whitecaps'
- 'Oregon OraclesOregon' should equal 'Oregon Oracles'

The tricky part here is the start of where it duplicates, isn't separated with a space.
So I can't just split them by ' ', remove duplicate words, and join.

I could cross-check each letter with each other letter. With a threshold of < 4 
repeating letters to qualify as a duplicate.

Looking for a better way though, that I have missed.

Comment: Could you just add a space between a capitalized letters and then remove duplicates and join? Unless the words are not always capitalized.

Comment: Need more info on: "What qualifies that given sequence of letters is a word or not" ... because StarsBlue can also be one word right ? Does that mean words with spaces should not be contained in coming words (as whole or included)

Comment: All three of the below answers get the job done. I prefer the last solution but it has been very helpful to go through each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```py
def mangle(s):
    for x in range(1, len(s)):
        suffix = s[-x:]
        if s.startswith(suffix):
            return (s[:-x], suffix)


for case in [
    "Blue Valley StarsBlue Valley",
    "West Michigan WhitecapsWest Michigan",
    "Oregon OraclesOregon",
    "Hello World",
    "123123",
]:
    print(case, "->", mangle(case))
```

Output:

```
Blue Valley StarsBlue Valley -> ('Blue Valley Stars', 'Blue Valley')
West Michigan WhitecapsWest Michigan -> ('West Michigan Whitecaps', 'West Michigan')
Oregon OraclesOregon -> ('Oregon Oracles', 'Oregon')
Hello World -> None
123123 -> ('123', '123')
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you provide, this could be achieved by splitting given uppercase instead of spaces:

```
import re
list(set([x.strip() for x in re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'Blue Valley StarsBlue Valley')]))
```

Which outputs:

```
['Blue','Valley','Stars']
```

If you wish a single string, add `' '.join()`:

```
' '.join(list(set([x.strip() for x in re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'Blue Valley StarsBlue Valley')])))
```

Which outputs:

```
'Valley Stars Blue'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

def dedup (inText):
    splitBySpace = inText.split()

    final = []
    for each in splitBySpace:
        if each not in final:
            checkFound = False
            for eachSavedToken in final:
                if eachSavedToken in each:
                    final.append(each.replace(eachSavedToken, ''))
                    checkFound = True
                    break            
            if not checkFound:
                final.append(each)


    return ' '.join(final)

for eachStr in ['Blue Valley StarsBlue Valley','West Michigan WhitecapsWest Michigan','Oregon OraclesOregon']:
    print (dedup (eachStr))
```

Output:

```
Blue Valley Stars
West Michigan Whitecaps
Oregon Oracles
```

This assumes that order is important. It is essentially a substr search.